# How to add intellisense to referenced c# libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am writing a plugin for an application that references the parent application API DLLs. I have recently been using a 'hidden' API within there that doesn't have the same level of IntelliSense content. i.e. none

As I learn the vagueries of this API, how can I add something in my own code to add IntelliSense to record what I learn about it?

Overload methods and add commenting to those?

Comment: In what sense is this API hidden? Does intellisense not work at all, or does it merely not have comments explaining the members? If it's merely missing comments, then you can add your own XML file describing the various members. You can see the format by ticking the "Generate XML documentation" tickbox in the project properties of one of your own projects, and looking at the generated file (it's perfectly understandable). Simply create one of these files, name it appropriately, and save it alongside the referenced DLL and you should get comments on the intellisense.

Comment: hidden in that there is no documentation of it within the published docs for the rest of the API, and also in cascade, no comments to the API methods as implemented.

Comment: Ok, so you have intellisense, but it is just the "barebones" of member name and parameter type/name? In which case, my answer should serve you well.

Comment: The 'hidden' methods are also not part of the . dropdown completion lists, will this cover that also and make them available for autocomplete?

Comment: No - you're problem is that you have no intellisense. How do you currently access these methods? Can you write normal code, or do you have to use reflection or similar?

Comment: Ordinarily, it is all fine; published and documented members are all available in the normal way. i happen to have stumbled on an internal developers blog which revealed a bunch of additional methods. I've been using these, but it would be nice to have them available in the same way. i.e. autocomplete and partially commented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134673/discussion-between-rb-and-jonathon).